# how to construct a valid file path and pass it to c++ library from a swift IOS application

Tags: c++, ios, file, swift

I'm writing an IOS application with swift that uses a c++ library that needs to load some text files.
I wrapped that library using C/ObjC so now I can call its methods from inside swift.
That library anyway accepts a relative/absolute char* pathname to a file or even a FILE* fd to a file.
What is a good strategy to obtain a path or a file descriptor that I can pass to underlying library from swift?
I guess that I have to bundle those files some way in the app project and then obtain a runtime an handler to those files and then get a pathname or a file descriptor.

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but I noticed that you got already some answers to your previous questions, but never *accepted* an answer. You can (and should) accept a helpful answer by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved, and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer. – See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information.

Comment: can´t upvote that comment more than once ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to iOS developing and arrived here looking for the same thing, as I wanted to read an array stored in a file and I was getting null when using fopen inside my C++ code. Solved it in the following way with XCode 6.3.2. Corrections or improvements are of course welcome.

1. Some context.
   I dragged some_file.txt to the project navigator next to my files (ViewController.swift, AppDelegate.swift, etc.). I also added a ccode.cpp file with this:

   ```
   #include "myccode.h"
   /*Some other includes*/

   #define MAX_AUT_SIZE        (1 << 22)

   typedef union {
       /* some data */
   } transition;

   transition data_struct[MAX_SIZE];
   unsigned data_size;

   FILE *the_file;   

   void read_my_file(const char * path) {
       if ((the_file = fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL){
           fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file");
       } else {
           fprintf(stderr, "Succees reading file");
       }

       data_size = fread(data_struct, sizeof data_struct[0], MAX_SIZE, the_file);
       fclose(the_file);

       /* Other code*/
   }

   /* Some other C++ functions that use the data structure which
    I just read from the file. */
   ```

   Added myccode.h with:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   #ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
   #endif

   void read_my_file(const char * path);
   /* The other C++ functions */

   #ifdef __cplusplus
   }
   #endif
   ```

In the My App Name > Supporting Files folder, I placed the file: My App Name-Bridging-Header.h. It only contains this:

`#include "ccode.h"`

2. The answer. To let C++ know the path to the file I used this in ViewController.swift.

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

       var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("some_file", ofType: "txt")
       var path2 = strdup(path!) /* Swift expects the argument to 
   have "UnsafePointer<Int8>" type. I don't really understand much of this */

       read_my_file(path2)

       /* Call some other C functions that use the data structure read from the file. 
   They work!! */

       }

   }
   ```

I only tested this in development. I have not yet submitted my first app to the store :P